# Can you use reflection to get the LocalVariables in an async method?

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to write a method that will programatically generate documentation about where certain types are used in an application. I am trying to use reflection to determine which methods create instances of these types. This works fine for regular methods, for example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var program = typeof(Program);
        
        var variablesTestMethod = program.GetMethod("VariablesTest").GetMethodBody().LocalVariables;

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public void VariablesTest()
    {
        var firstVariable = "First Variable";
        var secondVariable = 10;
    }
}
```

In this instance, `variablesTestMethodLocalVariables` is a list that contains 2 items, `System.String` and `System.Int32`, which is what I would expect. However, if the method is marked as async, this does not work.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var program = typeof(Program);

        var asyncVariablesTestMethod = program.GetMethod("AsyncVariablesTest").GetMethodBody().LocalVariables;

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public async Task AsyncVariablesTest()
    {
        var firstVariable = "First Variable";
        var secondVariable = 10;
    }
}
```

In this case, instead of a list containing the two variables, there is just one variable, and the type is listed as `LocalVariablesTest.Program+<AsyncVariablesTest>d__2`, which is not what I need.

Is there any way to determine the types referenced in an asynchronous method by using the `LocalVariables` property on the method body? Or is there another method or library that I could use to get what I need?

Comment: Note that `LocalVariables` just gives you the local *slots*. Those are things into which local variables can be placed. The compiler can re-use the same slot for multiple local variables (of the same type), or it can use local slots for things that you don't consider local variables (intermediate results in an expression for example), or it can turn local variables into things which just exist on the evaluation stack, and aren't stored in local slots at all. All of that is implementation-specific. You're not going to get accurate results that way, particularly if optimizations get involved

Comment: It's worth using https://sharplab.io to get a good feel for what the compiler generates in particular circumstances. Use a combination of the C# view (which will show you how those compiler-generated display classes for e.g. async methods work), and the IL view (show will show you how local slots are used, once you get comfortable reading IL)

Comment: Thank you, that insight is very helpful, and I was able to use [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/) to help me find what I needed to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to canton7's tip about using [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io), I was able to see that, for my async method, the compiler is generating a class that implements IAsyncStateMachine, with a `MoveNext()` method. This generated class had fields for the variables that I declared in my method, which I was able to access like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var program = typeof(Program).GetTypeInfo();

        var variable = program.GetMethod("AsyncVariablesTest").GetMethodBody().LocalVariables.Single();
        var methodVariables = program.GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredNestedType(variable.LocalType.Name).DeclaredFields;

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This was able to get me what I needed for my specific use case.

Comment: You cannot rely on this, though. This is a compiler implementation detail. If you've got the source available, it's *much* better to run it through Roslyn and inspect what it makes of things